# Unable to connect to my Ubuntu machine using Putty and WinSCP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, winscp

After upgrading phpmyadmin in my ubuntu server it shows connection error when i am connecting server via putty and winSCP.

How can i connect to the server?

Putty Fatal Error : Connection Time Out

I also tried connect using private key but still not able to connect It shows searching for host.... but not connect

Please help how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Connection Time Out means that your computer is unable reach the remote computer.

Try to ping your Ubuntu Server and check for an IP change.